# Determinant of a tensor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics

How to find the determinant of $\partial_{\lambda} \delta x^{\mu} $ where $\partial_{\lambda}$ is the four derivative and   $ \delta x^{\mu}$ is the del variation in $x^{\mu}$.
The answer is $\partial_{\mu} (\delta x^{\mu})$.

Comment: Have I a déjà-vu or have you already asked this question before?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/806981/2451

Comment: Hi Wajahat. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: *The answer is $\partial_{\mu} (\delta x^{\mu})$.* The determinant of this matrix is the same as its trace?